# Putting active class dynamically using Laravel segment method (Not working)

Tags: laravel, segment

I have four steps. Urls of each steps are -

**basic-info**   : `localhost/project/public/user/sell/basic-info`
**product-info** : `localhost/project/public/user/sell/5/product-info`
**photos**       : `localhost/project/public/user/sell/5/photos`
**price-info**   : `localhost/project/public/user/sell/5/price-info`

I want, when I am at basic-info then the basic-info step must have `active` class and rest of the steps will have `disabled` class.

And when I am at product-info then, the basic-info step will not have any class and product-info step will have `active` class and rest of the steps after that will have `disabled` class, and so on.

Below is the image.

[image]

Here is my code -

```
<div class="ui mini top four attached steps">
    <div class="{{ Request::segment(3) === 'basic-info' ? 'active' : '' }} step">
        <i class="info circle icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">Basic Info</div>
            <div class="description">Enter the basic information.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="{{ Request::segment(4) === 'product-info' ? 'active' : Request::segment(3) === 'basic-info' ? 'disabled' : '' }} step">
        <i class="help circle icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">Product Info</div>
            <div class="description">Enter your product details.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="{{ Request::segment(4) === 'photos' ? 'active' : Request::segment(3) === 'basic-info' ? 'disabled' : Request::segment(4) === 'basic-info' ? 'disabled' : '' }} step">
        <i class="image icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">Photos</div>
            <div class="description">Upload the photos of product.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="{{ Request::segment(4) === 'price-info' ? 'active' : Request::segment(3) === 'basic-info' ? 'disabled' : Request::segment(4) === 'basic-info' ? 'disabled' : Request::segment(4) === 'basic-info' ? 'disabled' : '' }} step">
        <i class="rupee icon"></i>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="title">Price</div>
            <div class="description">Enter the price</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a Helper function for this matter.

Here is what I'm using in one app:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;
use Route;

class Helper
{

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Detect Active Route
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Compare given route with current route and return output if they match.
    | Very useful for navigation, marking if the link is active.
    |
    */
    public static function isActiveRoute($route, $output = "active")
    {
        if (Route::currentRouteName() == $route) return $output;
    }
}
```

Register the class in `config\app.php` and an alias like `Helper`

`'Helper'    => App\Helpers\Helper::class,   //my custom functions`

and you can then use it like:

`class="{{ Helper::isActiveRoute('route.name') }}"`